# How to compare DictionaryEntry value faster than 'foreach' looping

Tags: c#

currently I use this to search a new string and compare with dictionary collection

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry value in hd)              
{ 
    if (value == newWordIn)
    {
        // assign existing word
    } 
    else 
    {
        // assign new word into collection
    }
}
```

hd contain so many key and make looping very long.
Anything can I do to make it fast checking and do not wait so long for check dictionary collection?

Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Your first mistake is using a hashtable like a list. Use the indexer instead.

Comment: `if (hd.ContainsValue(value))`

Comment: As noted in comments on my answer, the code you've given wouldn't even compile (you'd be comparing a DictionaryEntry with a string). It's really hard to help if you don't give accurate code. Also, you've changed the code in the question substantially without even commenting, making half of my answer look bizarre.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, no - if you're trying to find a dictionary entry **by value** then it will always be an O(N) operation. Instead, you should build a `HashSet<T>` of values, if you want this behaviour.

(Note that you really shouldn't be using the non-generic collections in the first place these days unless you *really* have to.)

Comment: Although O(n) for a small n .. can very well be faster than O(1).

Comment: @pst: Sure - but "hd contain so many key and make looping very long" is in the question.

Comment: Ahh, skipped that entirely :(

Comment: @pst: Sure - but "hd contain so many key and make looping very long" is in the question. – Jon Skeet (Yes that's what I mean)

Comment: For example we have a new String "Test" and wanna compare with an Array, then we can check it by doing Array.contain("Test") instead of looping, and maybe it will save some time.

Comment: @user1437001: Not really, because even then it's still going to loop internally. In order to find values efficiently, you need an appropriate data structure - which usually means using some sort of binary tree or hashing.

Comment: Assuming newWordIn is a string that won't compile.

Comment: @TonyLeeper: Whoops, yes - but neither would the OP's code. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce additional dictionary in which key is value from original dictionary, and value is count of those values in original dictionary. If values in original dictionary are unique (so count would always be 1) then you can use `HashSet` instead of `Dictionary`.

You'd need to make sure that two structures are always in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Could you also include the code to show what types you are using for `hd` and `newWordIn` to make the example clearer?

Assuming that in your example `newWordIn` is a `string` type, then that code will not compile as you are comparing it to a `DictionaryEntry` type.

As Jon Skeet already pointed out what you probably need is a `HashSet<string>`

It looks as though (from your code comments) that what you are trying to do is to ensure that your collection does not contain duplicate entries.  Then your code should read:

```
HashSet<string> hd = new HashSet<string>();

...

// Only add distinct entries
if (!hd.Contains(newWordIn))
{
    hd.Add(newWordIn);
}
```